# jquery datepicker adding event to next and previous button

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I display a datepicker with 3 months, and in the right corner there is the next button to go one month ahead. I want to add an event to this next button, i want to trigger an onther function with this button, but also the next month has to show up ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create click handler for this button using delegation with `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(){
     alert('next btn clicked');
});
```

Comment: tried in in firefox (firebug) and its working fine with click, so it's a explorer problem!

Comment: Have you refreshed IE cache?

Comment: Ya, works here on IE: http://jsfiddle.net/PF8ZQ/   Maybe test with mouseup instead of click but definitely, click should work

Comment: very strange, mousedown is working, but then the next month doenst appear